# How to split a list of pairs into a pair of lists?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
l = [('coronavirus', 96), ('virus', 30), ('rna', 26), ('human', 25), ('respiratory', 23)]
```

And I want to split into two like this:

```
l1 = ['coronavirus', 'virus', 'rna', 'human', 'respiratory']
l2 = [96, 30, 26, 25, 23]
```

I tried the following code but returns an AttributeError ('tuple' object has no attribute 'split')

```
l1, l2 = zip(*[map(int, x.split(',')) for x in l])
```

How can manage to split the list? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your elements are already tuples, it seems you are trying to operate on strings.

You can simply do

```
l1, l2 = zip(*l)
```

If you want `l1` and `l2` to be lists (instead of tuples), you can use `map(list, zip(*l))` or `[list(part) for part in zip(*l)]`

Comment: For reference, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip. In particular "zip() in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list".